# Select Iframe based on src value and change it

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am feeling stuck at trying to figure out this simple problem. I have an iframe tag that loads a youtube video:

```
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-card mdl-shadow--4dp portfolio-card"><iframe id="youtube" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/******" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I can select this iframe if this has an ID, example id="youtube" with this code:

```
document.getElementById('youtube').src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/WC3ONXJn9FQ';
```

But the problem is that my iframe does not have id, i was woundering if it was possible to get the element without id but match the src url and change the url?

***EDIT: i cannot use Jquery***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelector` to match an attribute:

```
var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe[src^="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/"]');
iframe.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/WC3ONXJn9FQ';
```

The `^=` operator matches an attribute that begins with the specific string.

Comment: vote up for explaining the operator. Worked like charm

Answer (score 1):

```
document.querySelector('iframe[src="old url"]').src = 'new url';
```

Check out CSS [Attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple with css attribute selectors and the `querySelector` function.

```js
const url = 'https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/******'


const iframe = document.querySelector(`iframe[src="${url}"`);

function changeIframeSrc(newUrl){
  iframe.setAttribute('src', newUrl);
}
```

```html
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-card mdl-shadow--4dp portfolio-card"><iframe id="youtube" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/******" frameborder="0"></iframe>

<button onclick="changeIframeSrc('https://www.youtube.com/embed/AaGK-fj-BAM')">Change Iframe SRC</button>
```